# Multiple $scope.$watch with different functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I want to watch two variables in my angularjs application using $scope.$watch. One is an `<input>` tag which I want to always watch, and the other is just a list `$scope.sample` which I want to cancel the $watch after the list is modified:

```
var listener = $scope.$watch(function(){
   ...
   listener()
})
```

I don't think I can have two `$scope.$watch` declarations in a single controller because angular complains that $digest is already in progress. How could I do this? Thanks!

Comment: You can indeed have 2 or more watch on your controller. Where are you getting the error. Share some code.

Comment: I don't think you're using it right.  [`$watch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope) takes an angular expression or function as the first argument which causes the second argument which is a function to be called when the value of the first argument changes.